# How to read managed metadata value from SPListItem

Tags: 2013, splistitem, taxonomy

I have a list in which there is one column which stores the Employee Department and it is of type Taxonomy field and it is stored in the user profile property.

I want to get the display value of that field as string.

My code is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dept = null;
        SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

        SPUser user = web.EnsureUser(web.CurrentUser.LoginName);          
        List<string> department = UserProfileHelper.GetUserProfilePropertyValue(site.Url,"Department",user,false);

        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        query.Query="<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Department\" /><Value Type=\"TaxonomyFieldType\">"+department[0]+
                    "</Value></Eq></Where>";

        query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title'/>";

        SPList list = web.Lists["Departments"];

        SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);



        foreach (SPListItem item in items)
        {
            TaxonomyField taxField = item["Department"] as TaxonomyField;
             dept = taxField.GetFieldValue("Department").ToString();
        }

        string url = web.Url + "/" + dept;

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url);

    }
```

In my code.. `GetUserProfilePropertyValue()` method returns the user profile property specified in the method.

I debugged the program and getting error at the line... `TaxonomyField taxField = item["oiplbDepartment"] as TaxonomyField;` that "Value does not fall in range".

The whole thing I am applying is in Visual Web Part.

How do I read the taxonomy field value?

Answer (score 2):

It was how I did in one of my projects.

```
TaxonomyField tf = currentPublishingPage.ListItem.Fields[NEWS_TAGS_COLUMN_NAME] as TaxonomyField;
TaxonomyFieldValueCollection tfvc = currentPublishingPage.ListItem["Enterprise Keywords"] as TaxonomyFieldValueCollection;
```

[Read the Full article](http://tech.just4sharing.com/Pages/sharepoint/Add-or-remove-enterprise-keyword-tagging-to-publishing-pages.aspx#.UmI-vRtmiSo)